# タグ機能 ストロングパラメーターで送れてきたタグ情報の","を取って保存する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

現在、ポートフォリオの投稿機能にハッシュタグ機能を実装に挑戦しております。

## 不明点

投稿フォームには下記のように、記入するよう促す予定です。

「タグ(タグ同士の間には半角の `,` を入れてください)」 → （例）A,B,C

その時、ストロングパラメーターで送られてきた値は `params{tagname: "A,B,C"}` になっております。
これをcreateメソッドで保存する際に、`.split(",")` を用いて、１つずつタグ情報を保存したいです。しかし、記述方法がわかりません。コントローラー内の記述方でアドバイス頂きたく。

現在のコントローラーは、添付の通りです。
今回はタグ機能実装に当たり、Formオブジェクトを使用しております。

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @post_form = PostForm.new
  end

  def create
    @post_form = PostForm.new(post_form_params)
    if @post_form.valid?
      @post_form.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def beautypage
    @beautypages = Post.where(genre: 1)
  end

  def troublepage
    @troublepages = Post.where(genre: 2)
  end


  private 

  def post_form_params
    params.require(:post_form).permit(:title, :genre, :detail, :tagname, images: []).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
end
```

下記は投稿フォーム内容

```
<%= form_with model: @post_form, url: url, method: method, id: 'new_post', local: true do |f|%>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title, "タイトル" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title, id:"post_title" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :images, "画像" %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true, id:"post_image" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :genre, "投稿ジャンル" %><br />
    <%= f.select :genre, [["美容投稿", 1], ["お悩み投稿", 2]], include_blank: "選択して下さい", id:"post_genre" %>
  </div> 

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :detail, "投稿内容" %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :detail, class: :form__text, id:"post_detail" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tagname, "タグ(タグ同士の間には半角の「,」を入れてください)", {class:"tag-label"} %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :tagname, placeholder: "（例）スキンケア,乾燥肌,肌荒れ", :class => "tag-field" %>
  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "投稿", class: :form__btn  %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

下記Formオブジェクトの中身　→ こちらで `,` を取り除いて保存するような記述にした方が好ましいですか？

```
class PostForm
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :title, :images, :detail, :genre, :tagname, :user_id, :post_id, :tag_id

  with_options presence: true do
    validates :title, length: { maximum: 50 }
    validates :genre
    validates :detail
    validates :user_id
  end

  def save
    post = Post.create(title: title, genre: genre, detail: detail, user_id: user_id ,images: images)
  
    tag = Tag.where(tagname: tagname).first_or_initialize
    tag.save
    
    PostTag.create(post_id: post.id, tag_id: tag.id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Form Objectをせっかく使っているのでしたら、今回のようにパラメータを処理するときにはそこでやるのが望ましいでしょう。コントローラーは基本的には薄くするべきです。

コード的には、

```rb
tagname.split(',').each do |name|
  tag = Tag.find_or_create_by(tagname: name)
  PostTag.create(post_id: post.id, tag_id: tag.id)
end
```

みたいな感じでしょうか。

Comment: Okura様ご回答頂きありがとう御座います。解決しました！！splitメソッドをeachメソッドで繰り返すような記載は、念頭に無かったので大変勉強になりました。